# Mercurial/Tortoiehg merge with branch without update

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I have a Hotfix and Trunk branches, so I need to merge fixes to my trunk.
All the guides tell me that I must first update to Trunk then merge with Hotfix.

That works, but I want to make subsequent merges, for instance if the fixes are really urgent. So I do not want to update to Trunk every time.

So the question is: Is there any way to merge my hotfix changes without updating to Trunk branch every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must always be updated to the branch that you wish to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but if you ever still need it, you can simply clone your repository again in another folder. Keep this folder under trunk. This way, you can merge hotfix to trunk wihout having to update your working folder.